# DynamoDB nested items inserting Android

Tags: android, database, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-dynamodb

Hey I am trying to integrate DynamoDB with my android app and insert items to the database that have nested objects with their own attributes like the `Video` object as the following :

```
User{ 
      "Name" : "MyName"
      "Video": {
                    "videoType": "BRIGHTCOVE",
                    "viewingTime": 156,
                    "videoSize": 7120441,
                    "url": "5378655747001",
                    "URL": "5378655747001"
                }
      "Password" : "123456"
```

any idea how it can be done and insert item inside an item? so far I only managed to add normal key-pair values like `Name` and `Password` with `document.put` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `put` operation parameters would need to look like this.  The `Video` attribute is a `Map` with simple key/value pairs.

```
{
  "TableName": "YOUR_TABLE_NAME",
  "Item": {
    "Name": {
      "S": "MyName"
    },
    "Password": {
      "S": "123456"
    },
    "Video": {
      "M": {      
        "videoType": {
          "S": "BRIGHTCOVE"
        },
        "viewingTime": {
          "N": "156"
        },
        "videoSize": {
          "N": "7120441"
        },
        "url": {
          "S": "5378655747001"
        },
        "URL": {
          "S": "5378655747001"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In Java (not tested)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create the DynamoDB Client with the region you want
        AmazonDynamoDB dynamoDB = createDynamoDbClient("YOUR REGION");
        
        try {
            PutItemRequest putItemRequest = new PutItemRequest();
            putItemRequest.setTableName("YOUR TABLE NAME");

            Map<String, AttributeValue> item = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>(); 
            item.put("PK", new AttributeValue("PK"));
            item.put("SK", new AttributeValue("SK"));
            
            Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValues = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>(); 
            attributeValues.put("videoType", new AttributeValue("BRIGHTCOVE"));
            attributeValues.put("viewingTime", new AttributeValue().withN("156"));
            attributeValues.put("videoSize", new AttributeValue().withN("7120441"));
            attributeValues.put("url", new AttributeValue("5378655747001"));
            attributeValues.put("URL", new AttributeValue("5378655747001"));

            item.put("Video", new AttributeValue().withM(attributeValues);
            putItemRequest.setItem(item);
            
            PutItemResult putItemResult = dynamoDB.putItem(putItemRequest);
            System.out.println("Successfully put item.");
            // Handle putItemResult

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // handle errors
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of how it can be done ? because when using Document API in Android it does not allow a `Map` attribute only `Set` or `DynamoDBEntry` types besides regular Primitives so I dont really understand how to execute this in the code

Comment: I haven't worked with the Document API in Java, but I cobbled together a code snippet to illustrate the concept.